# How to share apache /var/www using samba server in ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, samba, linux-networking, network-share

My issue is similar to the stackoverflow question, [virtual centOS 6.2 - How to share /var/www using Samba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11258096/8726370), however I am getting the following error:

```
Windows cannot access \server1\dev You do not have permission to access \\server1\dev
```

I installed ubuntu server and I am trying to give the `/var/www/html/dev` directory read and write permissions from other computers (ex: windows 7 and ubuntu desktop).

I changed the owner of folder `/var/www` to the `www-data` group and added user `dev1` to that group.  I then gave 0755 permission to the folder `/var/www` And below are the contents of my smb.conf file:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = ubuntu
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no

#============================ Share Definitions ============================== 
[sharing]
path = /samba/share
browsable =yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force user = nobody

[dev]
path = /var/www/html/dev
valid users = @www-data
read only = no
guest ok = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
```

So I am tried to access the `dev` share using a password.  I have also added a samba user by following [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/samba-server-ubuntu/), but when I attempt to access this share from windows 7 machine, I receive the following error message:

```
Windows cannot access \server1\dev.  You do not have permission to access \\server1\dev
```

**Additional information**

I can access `/samba/share` but cannot access the `dev` share.

EDIT: Now the windwos system asking to enter password. But after entering password I get the error `\\s1\dev is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.`

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled? If so you may have to change the type of the files and directories shared by httpd and smbd from httpd_sys_content_t to public_content_t (read-only) or public_content_rw_t (read-write).

Answer (score 1):

**Credit: Martin**

You need to change your samba mount configuration so that you give permission to the www-data user and group to write to it. You may or may not have the ability to set specific directory permissions, but if not you'll have to set the entire drive the write access (which is bad for security).

I would personally advise using nfs instead of samba shares for networked storage and the use of ext3 or other fully featured file system.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-set-permissions-to-samba-shares.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

http://www.mattvanstone.com/2006/06/automatically_mounting_smb_sha/

Answer (score 1):

**www-data** is a system account (<1000 uid/gid) and has no password at all.
I would not advice to use uid & gid below 1000. Instead create a new account or use an exsisiting one with uid >1000.

Maybe you want to create a new account for editing webpages via samba only. You can do this by creating a jail.

**Hint**: You dont need step 1 to 4 when using an exsisting user.

1. create a jail

```
# mkdir -p /srv/smb/exampleusername
```

2. Add an entry to */etc/fstab*

```
/var/www /srv/smb/exampleusername none bind 0 0
```

3. bind **/var/www** to **/srv/smb/exampleusername**, so you dont need to reboot to take effect of **fstab**

```
# mount -o bind /var/www /srv/smb/exampleusername
```

4. create a user, then remove his rights and put him in jail.

```
# adduser exampleuser
# chown root:root /home/exampleuser
# chmod 0755 /home/exampleuser
# usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin -d /srv/smb/exampleuser exampleuser
```

5. Change the rights of **www** to that new/specific user.

```
# chown -R exampleuser:exampleuser /var/www
# chmod -R 0755 /var/www
# chown exampleuser:exampleuser /srv/smb/www
# chmod 0755 /srv/smb/exampleuser
```

6. Example share for **smb.conf**

```
[www]
path = /srv/smb/exampleuser
comment = yada yada yada
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = exampleuser
writeable = yes
```

7. When not using **libpam-smbpass** then you need to add the user to smb-db too. I would not advice to use **libpam-smbpass** for security reasons, but this is up to you. Without this libary you need to add a password for that user.

```
# smbpasswd -a exampleuser
```

8. test your configuration

Done !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a linux login user account bill, you have installed samba. If you are running SELinux then there are a number of other commands you will need to execute.

Also, make sure you are not sharing smb to the world, your router or firewall should block port 137, 139, 445.

```
# Block the outside world from your server's smb shares
# assuming your local network is 192.168.0.*
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP ! -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m multiport -p tcp --dports 139,445

# Add your user account "bill" to www-data
usermod -aG www-data bill
# Give bill an smb password
smbpasswd -a bill
# Set permissions in the html folder for www-data
# WARNING: existing apps might require specific permissions on specific folders
# web code can now alter existing -/html/dev folder files
chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/dev

# alternatively, in combination with create mask 775 in smb.conf
chown root:www-data -R /var/www/html/dev
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/dev

# add the following text to the bottom of /etc/samba/smb.conf
[dev]
path = /var/www/html/dev
available = yes
valid users = @www-data
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = no
writable = yes
create mask = 0775
force user = www-data
force group = www-data
```

An alternative might be to not set any other permissions but include force user and group as root, but that seems quite a bit scary to me.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution, Apache/Nginx/PHP/etc. will still have operational write access as ***www-data*** to */var/www*, while a developer has write access with his user account below */var/www*:

1. Add the developers/admins user name to the web servers group, usually ***www-data***:
   sudo usermod -a -G www-data ***UsernameOfSambaShare***
2. Guess your public files are below */var/www*, then grant write access recursive to the group:
   sudo find /var/www -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod **775**
   sudo find /var/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod **664**
   sudo chown www-data:***GroupnameOfSambaShareUser*** -R /var/www
3. Prepare */etc/smb.conf* for the write access of the new group member to the shared folder:
   *[www]

   force create mode = **664**

   force directory mode = **775**

   writeable=yes

   guest ok=yes

   path=/var/www

   comment="Public area"

   write list = ***UsernameOfSambaShare*** ...

   valid users = ***UsernameOfSambaShare*** ...*

Of course you can have different permissions for multiple shares below */var/www* as long as all the users are in the group ***www-data***.

If the web server needs write access to the files or folders provided via the Samba share, you will have to add the user www-data to the group(s) of the Samba share user(s) or correct the permissions (see point 2).

**A warning:**
This configuration is not recommended for a production system, as it weakens the security concept of the web server.
However, it is very useful for a development environment in which you need to write data to a virtual machine, for example.

Comment: Or you scrap the whole useless chown stuff and use ACL.